# Moving on from a while loop to an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Let's say I want this code to have the user pick one of three animals (dog, cat, pig), then have the computer reply with whatever sound the animal makes (i.e. "dog" -> "woof"). BUT, I want to be able to stop the user from entering in any other animal that isn't a dog, cat, or pig using a while statement.

When I do this, the while statement runs and loops, but if you enter "dog", it still prints "That isn't a valid animal.", when I want it to move on to the if statement below it. What's causing this?

```
String animal = keyboard.nextLine();

  while (!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")||!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("cat")||!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("pig")) {
            System.out.println("That isn't a valid animal.");
            animal = keyboard.nextLine();
  }
        if (animal.equals("dog"){
        System.out.println("Woof")
        }
```

Comment: With the way your braces are structured, the code is broken.  If you added a closing brace at the *end* of these statements, your code would be incorrect.  If you added a closing brace *before* the `if` statement, your code would work.

Comment: I'd consider using a `do-while` loop instead, as you need to perform the pass validation at the end of the loop

Comment: `!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")||!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("cat")||!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("pig")` should be `!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("dog") && !animal.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") && !animal.equalsIgnoreCase("pig")`, remember the whole condition needs to evaluate to `false` to break the loop (i.e. the loop will continue while the condition is `true` `while (true) do...`)

Comment: @Makoto there was a bracket there, I just left it out when I created the post whoops

Comment: @MadProgrammer changing the ||'s to &&'s did it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")` means "animal is not equal to `dog`". When you input `dog`, this condition is `false` because animal is equal to `dog`.

The `||` operator is a short-circuit operator which means the right-side is only evaluated when we can't reach the answer from the left side. So when the left side is `true` (animal not equal `dog`) we can stop there. But when the left side is false (animal equals `dog`), we need to check the next condition to see if that's true. In your case, that's "animal not equal to `cat`". Since `dog` is not equal to `cat`, this is true, and your code prints out `"That isn't a valid animal."`

The simplest fix is to change `||` to `&&`, but the real problem is that `!a && !b` is counter-intuitive. Your condition is "Animal is not equal to `dog`, `cat`, or `pig`", so you could write it as:

```
while( !( animal.equalsIgnoreCase("dog") || animal.equalsIgnoreCase("cat") || animal.equalsIgnoreCase("pig") ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this logic

```
!animal.equalsIgnoreCase("dog") || !animal.equalsIgnoreCase("cat")
```

This can be expressed as `NOT(dog) OR NOT(cat)`

Well, if it *is* a dog, it **is not** a cat. This makes the statement true. And vice-versa.

This statement is also true if you type anything because it's not a dog or a cat.

---

Instead you want to write `NOT (dog OR cat)` or `NOT(dog) AND NOT(cat)`

---

Alternatively, you can use a `while(true)`

```
while (true) {
    String animal = keyboard.nextLine();
    switch (animal) {
       case "dog":
         System.out.println("Woof");
         break;
       case "cat":
         break;
       default:
         System.out.println("That isn't a valid animal.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a set of accepted values, this way it is easy to add more animals without having to add more logical statements to your while loop

```
HashSet<String> validAnimals = new HashSet<>();
validAnimals.add("dog");
validAnimals.add("cat");
validAnimals.add("pig");
//easy to add more valid animals

String input = keyboard.nextLine();

//only have to call contains() on the set
while(!validAnimals.contains(input.toLowerCase()))
{
    System.out.println("That isn't a valid animal.");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```